# Ruby Regexp: How to match parts of string separated some word

Tags: ruby, regex

I have such a string:

`<span>test text 1</span> some text <span>test text 2<span>test text 3</span></span>`

I want to retrieve second case (after "some text", with nested span), i.e. `<span>test text 2<span>test text 3</span></span>` and match text of top-level span and text in inside span: `test text 2` and `test text 3` (but not `test text 1`)

My regexp: `<span.*?>(.*?)<span.*?>(.*?)<\/span><\/span>`

But I get it:

[image]

How I should fix regexp to get `test text 2` and `test text 3` match groups and ignore first span (without nesting)?

Comment: If this is HTML, can't you use an HTML parser in Ruby?

Comment: @stribizhev hmmm.. good question! But I believe there is simple solution with regexp)

Comment: Yes, it can be done with regex, but it will look ugly, and the answer is most likely downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
(?!<span.*<\/span>.*<span)<span.*?>(.*?)<span.*?>(.*?)<\/span><\/span>
```

It works great

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
s = "<span>test text 1</span> some text <span>test text 2<span>test text 3</span></span>"
matches = s.scan(/<span.*?>.*?<\/span.*?>/)
p matches[1] # "<span>test text 2<span>test text 3</span>"
```